# extract library version from binary with CMake

Tags: c, cmake, version, external-dependencies

I am writing a `FindXXX.cmake` script for an external C library. I would like my script to provide information about the library version. However, the library only provides this information in the form of a function that returns the version number as a string.

I thought I could extract the version number by having `FindXXX.cmake` compile the following C program on the fly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"

int main() {
  char version[256];
  get_version(version);
  puts(version);
  return 0;
}
```

In order for this to work, CMake should compile and run the program above at configure time, and use the information it prints as the version identifier. I know how to do the latter ([`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/execute_process.html)), and I *almost* know how to do the former: [`CheckCSourceRuns`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/CheckCSourceRuns.html) comes to mind, but I do not know how to capture the stdout of the generated executable.

**TL;DR**: is there a way to compile a program, run it and capture its stdout from CMake at generation time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [try_run](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/try_run.html) for that purpose (it is assumed that your source file is named as `foo_get_version.c`):

```
try_run(foo_run_result foo_compile_result
        foo_try_run ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/foo_get_version.c
        RUN_OUTPUT_VARIABLE foo_run_output)

if(NOT foo_compile_result)
    # ... Failed to compile
endif()
if(NOT foo_run_result EQUAL "0")
    # ... Failed to run
endif()

# Now 'foo_run_output' variable contains output of your program.
```

---

Note, that `try_run` isn't executed when *cross-compiling*. Instead, CMake expects that the user will set cache variables `foo_run_result` and `foo_run_result__TRYRUN_OUTPUT`.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I didn't get the last bit about cross-compilation, though. Care to elaborate?

Comment: When cross-compile, you *may link* with the library (that is, *compile* your program), but **cannot load** the library (that is, *run* your program). This is because the *host* platform (where you run `cmake`) differs from the *target* platform (where the library is intended to be loaded). In that case you need some other way for obtain version of the library. E.g., you may ask the user to run your program on *target* machine, and set certain CMake cache variables according to that run.